# How to automatically hide notifications after a timeout in OS X Sierra?

Tags: macos, notifications

Is it possible to configure the notifications that they disappear after a timeout in OS X Sierra?

Currently they never disappear until I click on them, which is super annoying. I can't find any settings in the UI to configure this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

System Prefs > Notifications
On a per-app basis, you need to switch from Alerts to Banners ...

> Banners appear in the upper-right corner and go away automatically. Alerts stay on screen until dismissed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to this Apple Developer Manual [entry](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayDialogsandAlerts.html), in AppleScript you programmatically dismiss an alert after a specified period of time.

```
display dialog "Do, or do not. There is no try." giving up after 5
--> Result: {button returned:"OK", gave up:true}
```